# How to send my own parameters to AddHandler

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, handler

I'm trying to send my own parameter (**Index As Integer** instead of **sender As Object, e As EventArgs**) to an AddHandler. Here's my code:

```
Dim Button_ as Button
For Index=0 To 9
    Button_ = New Button()
    Button_.Left = 10
    Button_.Top = (Index * 30) + 10
    Button_.Width = 100
    Button_.Height = 20
    AddHandler Button_.Click, AddressOf Button_Click(Index)
    Me.Controls.Add(Button_)
Next

Sub Button_Click(Index As Integer)
    'Do stuff here...
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change signature of Click event handler, but you can detect which button was clicked if you assign it's Name (I assume it's a WinForm button).

```
Dim Button_ as Button
For Index=0 To 9
    Button_ = New Button()
    Button_.Left = 10
    Button_.Top = (Index * 30) + 10
    Button_.Width = 100
    Button_.Height = 20

    Button_.Name = "Button_" & Index.ToString()

    AddHandler Button_.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
    Me.Controls.Add(Button_)
Next
```

You can then use standard signature like this:

```
Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
     Dim Button_ as Button = CType(sender, Button)
     Dim ButtonName = Button.Name
End Sub
```

You can derive actual index from Name if needed.

```
Dim Index as Integer = CInt(ButtonName.Substring(7))
```

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Please mark the solution as answer if it was useful

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other answers, your button has a property called [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it is defined as an object.  I usually use this property when I need to use a common event handler with a Control Array, you would use it something like this.

```
Dim Button_ as Button
For Index=0 To 9
    Button_ = New Button()
    Button_.Left = 10
    Button_.Top = (Index * 30) + 10
    Button_.Width = 100
    Button_.Height = 20
    Button_.Tag = Index
    AddHandler Button_.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
    Me.Controls.Add(Button_)
Next

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim i As Integer = CInt((CType(sender, Button).Tag))
    ' Use your index accordingly
End Sub
```